# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle Display expiresAt in twig template

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I want to display the expiresAt in my twig but i have this error :

```
 Method "expiresat" for object "AuthenticationBundle\Entity\User" does not exist in AdminNCBundle:NC:list_clients.html.twig at line 43
```

in my twig i have done a for :

```
   {% for client in clients %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ client.firstname }} {{ client.lastname }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.telephone }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.registrationdate|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.expiresat|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.duration }}</td>
        </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

the registrationdate displayed very well.

Comment: On the assumption that your entity User extends the FOSUserBundle Model User, you will need to add a method to your entity to `getExpiresAt()` since there is no such method in FOSUserBundle.

Comment: thank you for your answer its correct i added a method in my User entity         public function getExpiresAt() {
        return $this->expiresAt;
    }   because FOSUserBundle Model User dosen't has a getExpiresAt method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [answer of geoB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755231/symfony2-fosuserbundle-display-expiresat-in-twig-template#comment61090869_36755231) is correct

i added a method in my `User` entity

```
public function getExpiresAt() { 
    return $this->expiresAt; 
}
```

because FOSUserBundle Model User dosen't has a `getExpiresAt` method