# FOSUserBundle setExpiresAt($date) doesn't work?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I want to modify the expires_at of my client , when i do persist($client) and flush(); every method works fine except setExpiresAt() it doesn't change the value in table.

```
$client = $em->getRepository('ClientBundle:Client')->FindClient($id);

$expiresat = $client->getExpiresAt(); // the can see the (*) 
$expiresat->modify($durationcontract);
$client->setExpiresAt($expiresat);

// $durationcontract can be 6 months or one year
$client->setDuration($durationcontract);

$em->persist($client);
$em->flush();
```

(*) this method doesn't exist in Class User or the FOSUserBundle its created by me. you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755231/symfony2-fosuserbundle-display-expiresat-in-twig-template)

Comment: what is $durationcontract?

Comment: the duration of the contract of the client can be 6 months or 1 year

Comment: so, it is `'+6 month'` or `'+1 year'` right?

Comment: yes it can be written like this $expiresat->modify('+6 month');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe Doctrine doesn't see the difference between objects.

So, try this:

```
$expiresat = $client->getExpiresAt();
$expiresat = clone $expiresat;
$expiresat->modify($durationcontract);
$client->setExpiresAt($expiresat);
```